# Gitlab runner (windows docker) is omitting characters in script calls

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, docker-for-windows

When I call a script in my gitlab-ci yml file, sometimes some characters within the call are skipped, such that the command cannot be executed anymore.

An example:
The call of

`$ Scripts/build_all.bat Argument1 Argument2`

results in:

`Script/build_all.bat : The term 'Script/build_all.bat' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.`

As you can see, the shell omits the 's' in the path 'Scripts'.

I could post many other examples, where characters are omitted, it can happen at different locations in the call.

My environment: 
Docker Windows with gitlab runner 13.10.3. The docker image is based on mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019

Comment: You are not the only one with this issue: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/27394

Recommend you add your voice to that issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link! I will try to share my experiences in there as well!